# Add Image and Hyperlink control to panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ado.net

I want to add Image and Hyperlink In Panel_video_1,Panel_video_2 and Panel_video_link1, Panel_video_link2 respectively,But my code take all the Images and Hyperlinks to last Panel.I want to add these controls in separate panel.

code behind:

```
String sql1 ="SELECT  title, video_id ,image_path FROM up_video WHERE Video_types='Song Video' ";
adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(sql1, cn);
ds = new DataSet();
adpt.Fill(ds, "title");
var lastUploaded = ds.Tables["title"].AsEnumerable().OrderByDescending(r => r.Field<int>("video_id")).Take(3);
foreach (DataRow row in lastUploaded)
    {

        int videoID = row.Field<int>("video_id");
        Image img = new Image();
        img.ID = "image" + videoID;
        string title = row.Field<string>("title");
        img.ImageUrl = row.Field<string>("image_path");
        img.Height = 150;
        img.Width = 150;
        HyperLink hl = new HyperLink();
        hl.ID = "hyperlink" + videoID;
        string linktitle = row.Field<string>("title");
        hl.Text = linktitle;
        hl.NavigateUrl = "Downloadpage.aspx?name=" + linktitle;
        hl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        Panel_video_1.Controls.Add(img);      
        Panel_Video_link1.Controls.Add(hl);
        Panel_video_2.Controls.Add(img);              
        Panel_video_link2.Controls.Add(hl);
        Panel_video_3.Controls.Add(img);               
        Panel_video_link3.Controls.Add(hl);
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

One `image / hyperlink` object could be added to only one `panel`, when you add to second it is removed from first and so on. You have to create three objects of image and to add to three panels.